# Android Alarm repeats only once using AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager to create an alarm that is supposed to be repeated every x seconds. The alarm indeed fires onces, then again after the desired period of time but then never again.

Here is my code

MyActivity.java

```
// Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval = 3000; // 3 sec

manager.setRepeating(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
    interval,
    pendingIntent);
```

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I run my application I see a Toast saying "I'm running" and then 5 (not 3 for some reason) seconds later another toast. After that I see nothing else.

How can I make my alarm to keep repeating until I stop it?

Comment: In my experience the fastest an alarm can trigger is once per minute. Use a handler instead.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I think you are a bit wrong. Even in the official documentation they give an example for interval and they mention 5 seconds. There are also a lot of tutorials that demostrate how to use repeating alarms and they use the interval of several seconds. Therefore, problem seems to be in something else.

Comment: Please mention source when quoting something. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html The page looks like it has last been updated when KitKat came out. We're 5 years later now and there's been a great effort to conserve battery life which may have resulted in behavior I described. The same page also says `Note: For timing operations that are guaranteed to occur during the lifetime of your application, instead consider using the Handler class in conjunction with Timer and Thread. This approach gives Android better control over system resources.`

Comment: @Spartakos Can you try to change the type of the interval variable from `int` to `long` and change the `SystemClock` to `System`?

Comment: @Marat SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() is not interchangeable with System.currentTimeMillis(). You can pass int as long parameter. There is not an overload distinguishing between int and long, what's the point?

Comment: `As of Android 4.4 (API Level 19), all repeating alarms are inexact.` In my case I used `setExact` and rescheduled the alarm within the receiver. Then it triggered only once per minute. Ergo: use a Handler for shorter exact intervals.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Ohh, I meant to use `AlarmManager.RTC` too. Sorry for that. About data type: I thought that we always need to pass `long`. In every tutorial or any other example in web the authors pass long variables. Please, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Marat `AlarmManager.setRepeating` has only one definition and int can be coerced to long in Java e.g. `long something = 2;`. There is no problem in this regard. If it were the other way around, you'd have to explicitly cast e.g. `int something = (int) 6L;`.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Ok, Thanks for clarification. But what about Elapsed_Time and RTC? Isn't it better to use RTC?

Comment: @Marat http://mydailycodingexperience.blogspot.cz/2016/08/systemcurrenttimemillis-vs.html

Comment: @Marat The `System` does not have the method I'm using. If I were to change to `System` I'd have to use `RTC_WAKEUP` and I've already tried it. Not working.

Comment: @Spartakos it has `currenttimemillis()`

Comment: @Marat As I stated, I'd have to use `RTC` flag with `currenttimemillis()`. Anyway the result is the same!